# ng-repeat and nested array in json

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have some problems accessing some values stored in a json with the directive ng-repeat.

the json is formatted properly (checked it with a json checker) and it's called via $http service. unfortunately i can't change the format of json, retrieved through the wordpress-json-api plugin.

the json (with some cuts):

```
    {
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 10,
    "count_total": 24,
    "pages": 3,
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 108,
            "type": "sensor",
            "slug": "ert",
            "custom_fields": {
                "sensor_id": [
                    "er"
                ],
                "coords": [
                    "{\"address\":\"\",\"lat\":55.39979700000003,\"lng\":10.430533275390644,\"zoom\":12}"
                ]
            }
        }

        //etc other posts following, json correct
```

Now i have a problem accessing the single values inside coords. i complained too about serializing data in db, but i'd like anyway to get lng and lat out of that array

```
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="post in sensor.posts">
        <h4>name : {{post.id}}</h4> //ok
        <h4>all custom fields : {{post.custom_fields}}</h4> //good-this-too
        <h4>custom field lat : {{post.custom_fields.prova_coords[0]}}</h4> //works but can't go on
    </li>

</ul>
```

the ouput of last line is:

```
custom field lat : {"address":"","lat":55.39979700000003,"lng":10.430533275390644,"zoom":12}
```

but now i'm stuck..can't retrieve single lat and long values

Comment: I'm thinking you may need to use `$scope.$eval(field)` to get back a usable javascript object

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$scope.$eval(coordsString)`

Here's a test: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/Rnc7R/

```
var objString = "{\"address\":\"\",\"lat\":55.39979700000003,\"lng\":10.430533275390644,\"zoom\":12}";

$scope.coords = $scope.$eval(objString);
```

Then you can refer to `coords.lat` or `coords.lng` in your template like so:

```
<div ng-controller="myCoordsCtrl">
    Lattitude: {{coords.lat}}<br>
    Longitude: {{coords.lng}}
</div>
```

Since this is happening within an `ngRepeat` you may need to use an Angular filter to rectify the string on the fly

```
<li ng-repeat="post in sensor.posts | myRectifyCoordsFilter">
```

**EDIT**:

Don't use the filter like in the above example, using filters to modify `$scope` is not a good situation.  You'll need to modify your `$scope` prior to using it in the `ng-repeat`

```
$http.get().success(function(data){
    angular.forEach(data,function(val,key){
        this.coords = $scope.$eval(val.coords[0]);
    },data);
    $scope.sensor = data;
});
```

Comment: thanks conroy, neat! anyway i can't get to make it work inside the function i have.. $http.get().success(function(data){$scope.sensor = data;... }) or i should "objectify" everything?

Comment: Its most likely because you're using `ng-repeat` and need to convert the coords in `$scope` on the fly.  Looking up how to do this my first inclination was to use a filter but I see that can be a problem since filter's aren't meant to modify `$scope` variables and is otherwise frowned upon.  You'll have to do it in your success function, unfortunately if there are many posts this could be a performance hit.